# how to change the layout print in textarea with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, layout, textarea

hello guys in my code I created an array with random numbers. 
I print this array in a textarea and precisely displays like this:

```
5,52,5,4,8,4,3,4,8,6,1,4,58,3,4,8,3,1,8
```

now I want to make sure to change the print of the numbers in the textarea. I would like to see them in vertical and in particular:

```
5 
52 
5 
4 
8 
4 
3 
4 
8 
6 
1 
4 
58 
3 
4 
8 
3 
1 
8
```

the layout changes must take place when the user selects a radio button
In fact, I have:

```
radio buttons horizontally 
radio buttons vertically
```

Who knows enlighten me?

Comment: Have you written any code to try and accomplish this, or are you just expecting us to do your job for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
rewrote using non-jquery.  Allows for some basic text in textfield.

**JSFiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/deEP5/

**HTML:**

```
<input id="radio1" type="radio" name="hv" value="horizontal" checked/>Horizontal
<br/><input id="radio2" type="radio" name="hv" value="vertical"/>Veritical   
<br/>
<textarea id="text">Some text, random stuff.

Other text.

</textarea>
```

**JS:**

```
function toggleNumbers(){
    if(this.value == 'horizontal'){
        document.getElementById('text').value = document.getElementById('text').value.replace(/(\d)\n?/g,"$1,").replace(/(\d),(\D)/g,"$1 $2").replace(/(\d),$/g,"$1");  
    } else {
        document.getElementById('text').value = document.getElementById('text').value.replace(/(\d),?/g,"$1\n");                   
    }
}

document.getElementById('radio1').addEventListener('click',toggleNumbers);
document.getElementById('radio2').addEventListener('click',toggleNumbers);     

var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
document.getElementById('text').value = document.getElementById('text').value + arr.join(",");
```

**CSS**

```
textarea {
    height:200px;
    width:300px;
}
```

Comment: I am not making use of JQuery. 

I changed to this the code of kevin:

[code]
var numbers = document.getElementById("Textarea").innerHTML.split(",");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < ordina.length; i++)
{

document.getElementById("Textarea").innerHTML = (this.value == "verticale") ? numbers.join("\n"):numbers.join(","); 
         
}
[/code]

the problem arises here: 

I also have the text inside the textarea so the split method does not act and the code does not work.

Comment: Perhaps put updated code in an EDIT inside your original post. We can work from there.

Comment: Updated my code to support text in the textarea as well.  The regexes look for comma delimited lists of numbers, or line-break delimited lists and act on them specifically, ignoring other basic text.

Comment: I don't understand your question?

Comment: Scusi. Tuttavia, il codice Proprio non Riesco a rientrare in miniera. E il Che Kevin non funziona Perchè C'E Una Parte di testo. Potreste aiutarmi a LIVELLO locale? Se mi SI Passa il Vostro contatto chat skype Sarei grato. Grazie ..

Comment: Do you want me to rewrite it without jQuery?  Is that the issue?

Comment: Yes, please. Without query.

Comment: Check now.  It is rewritten without jquery.

Comment: wow, you're a magician. Thank you very much! You gave me a great help! Peace!

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<textarea id="ta">5,52,5,4,8,4,3,4,8,6,1,4,58,3,4,8,3,1,8</textarea>
<input type="radio" name="orientation" value="vertical"/> Vertical
<input type="radio" name="orientation" value="horizontal"/> Horizontal
```

**Javascript**

```
var numbers = document.getElementById("ta").value.split(",");
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
  inputs[i].onclick=function(){
      document.getElementById("ta").value = (this.value == "vertical") ? numbers.join("\n"):numbers.join(","); 
  }            
}
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/88KyJ/1/